# how to display few price fields for product in virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I need to add few price fields on product display in virtuemart, and check box near each price field

For example, when you buy this product, price depends on weight, and you need to select in check box

50ml
75ml 
100ml

and near each checkbox, product price input field will be displayed.

How to realise this thing and is there any solution, that already done

Thanks, Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup child (sub) products of your main product. This way you can have the description and images in the parent product and each child product will have an attribute and price associated with it. Have a google on "virtuemart setup child products" or something like that.